# How is exception syntax in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I'm using SMTP and SSH libs, it works all fine in Python 2.7, but there is a problem in Python3.
examples:

```
try:
    server.login(user, passwd)
    flag = 0
except smtplib.SMTPException, err:
```

and

```
    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        if timeout_sec is not None:
            ssh.connect(target, username='', password='', timeout=timeout_sec)
        else:
            ssh.connect(target, username='', password='')
        exit = 0
        break
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException, ssherr:
```

the exception examples are not working. How can I fix this?

```
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException, ssherr:
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Python 3 requires the `as` syntax. The comma syntax is from Python 2.x. The most recent versions of Python 2.x (2.6/2.7) support `as` syntax so it should be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

```
except smtplib.SMTPException as err:

except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as ssherr:
```

See the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement